# SQL Join expression not supported

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

Below is my query:

```
SELECT 
   UT.AgentName AS [Agent Name], 
   UT.TeamName AS Team, 
   Format(Now(),"Short Date") AS [As Of], 
   Sum(I.RegPointValue) AS Points
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       UU.AgentID, 
       (Nz(UU.LastName,'')+", "+Nz(UU.FirstName,'')) AS AgentName , 
       TT.TeamName 
    FROM 
       Users AS UU 
      INNER JOIN 
       Teams AS TT 
      ON UU.TeamID = TT.TeamID) AS UT 
 LEFT JOIN 
    (InfractionTypes AS I 
   INNER JOIN 
      (DateCodes AS D 
     INNER JOIN 
        AquiredInfractions AS AI 
     ON D.DateID = AI.DateID) 
   ON I.InfractionID = AI.InfractionID)
 ON UT.AgentID = AI.AgentID
WHERE (((D.DateValue)>=#4/1/2014#))
GROUP BY UT.TeamName, UT.AgentName, I.RegPointValue;
```

What this does is sum up all of the points that a person would get depending upon the attendance infractions that they have recieved. If I change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` the query works but only returns the names of people that have received attendance infractions. But what I would like is for it to return the names of all people and have 0 for their points if they haven't received any.

The error that I get when I try to save or execute is `Join expression not supported`. I have been trying to get this to work for the last few hours by messing with the order of the joins but to no avail. Using MS-Access 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some aliases.

Every inner query used as a table *must* be given an alias, and when joining them you must use that alias and only the selected columns on the join condition.

For example, add aliases to these lines:

```
...
    ON D.DateID = AI.DateID) AS SOMETHING_1
  ON I.InfractionID = AI.InfractionID) AS SOMETHING_2
```

etc

Comment: After sleeping on it, I understood what you meant and got it to work. Thank you.