# MS Access multi (INNER, LEFT & RIGHT) JOIN query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010, outer-join

Ok, here's the thing.  I have the Following tables involved :

```
> YEARS
------------------------------ 
ID    YEAR      ACTUAL
------------------------------ 
1     2014-15   TRUE 
2     2015-16   FALSE


> SHOPS
------------------------------ 
ID    NAME     ...
------------------------------ 
1     ThisShop ...


> ITA
------------------------------ 
ID    YEAR_ID   SHOP_ID
------------------------------ 
1     1         1 
2     1         2 
...


> INSPECTORS
------------------------------ 
ID    INSPECTOR
------------------------------ 
1     M. Black
2     M. White
3     M. Brown
...


> ITA_INSPECTORS
-------------------------------------------------------
ID    ID_ITA    ID_INSPCTR     StartDate    EndDate
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the thing, I want a query to display ALL the `INSPECTORS`, listed or not in `ITA_INSPECTORS` for the `SHOPS ID = 1 AND YEARS ID = 1`.  If the inspector is present in the `ITA_INSPECTORS` table, show the Start and End dates, if not, show without the dates.

Note that there might not be an `ITA_ID` in the `ITA_INSPECTORS` table for a selected shop (imagine the `ITA_INSPECTORS` table is empty, I wouls still need to view all of the INSPECTOR names).

The `INSPECTORS` table is static data to build the `ITA_INSPECTORS` table.

I have tried this query :

```
SELECT * FROM ((ITA 
INNER JOIN YEARS ON ITA.ID_YEAR = YEARS.ID)
LEFT JOIN ITA_INSPECTORS ON ITA.ID = ITA_INSPECTORS.ID_ITA)
RIGHT JOIN INSPECTORS ON ITA_INSPECTORS.ID_INSPCTR = INSPECTORS.ID
WHERE ITA.SHOP_ID = 1 AND ((YEARS.ACTUAL) = True);
```

It works until I add the `RIGHT JOIN` clause, then I get an error saying `Join expression not supported`.

Can anybody guide me to the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Try searching for "Join expression not supported" in the ms-access tab.  There are quite a few relevant questions - chances are one of them solves your problem (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337630/sql-join-expression-not-supported))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one solution is to split the query so that it doesn't have these *conflicting* joins
So create a query e.g q1

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (
        ITA INNER JOIN YEARS ON ITA.ID_YEAR = YEARS.ID
        ) LEFT JOIN ITA_INSPECTORS ON ITA.ID = ITA_INSPECTORS.ID_ITA
    )
```

and then create a 2nd query to make the right join you need

```
SELECT INSPECTORS.ID, INSPECTORS.INSPECTOR, q1.*
FROM INSPECTORS LEFT JOIN q1 ON INSPECTORS.ID = q1.ID_ITA;
```

Comment: I had to modify slightly by doing two different sub-forms to manage to display the way I wanted but it eventually worked out thanks to this technic.